# How to perform rowcallback on 1 column only with R DT datatable

Tags: r, dt

In a datatable like the one below, I am failing to change the `rowCallback` to only change 1 column, lets say i = 2. I tried to alter the `for (i = 1` .... statement, but I keep ending up with blank tables

```
datatable(cars/10,options = list(
    rowCallback = JS(
        "function(row, data) {",
        "for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {",
        "if (data[i]>1000 | data[i]<1){",
        "$('td:eq('+i+')', row).html(data[i].toExponential(1));",
        "}",
        "}",
        "}")
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to apply your code for i=2 only:

```
datatable(cars/10, 
          options = list(
            rowCallback = JS(
              "function(row, data) {",
              "  if (data[2]>1000 || data[2]<1) {",
              "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toExponential(1));",
              "  }",
              "}")
          )
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks Stefan, no need to do the if(i = 2) structure indeed. Still not sure why I could not get that if statement to work though

Comment: And final follow up, what if I also want to drop the >1000  || <1 condition and just want to do toExponential no matter what to column 2? I got that to work with if (data[2]) {".... but seems silly, and data[2]$('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toExponential(1)); doesn't work

Comment: @Mark Just remove the `if` statement (and do `$('td:eq(2)', row).html(...`, not `data[2]$('td:eq(2)', row).html(...`)

Comment: cool thanks Stephane, in the mean time I also found this line of code which you could use for 1 column without the need to rowcallback, but I will use your answer